# Updating a related model without finding the parent initially but populating it on update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am using ef-core 2.1 rc1, I have a dependent model with a navigation property defined as a complex object:

```
public class ChildModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ParentModel Parent { get; set; }
}
```

In a view I get the `Id` and an updated `Name`, I can update the object without fetching the navigation property, however I would like to retrieve the navigation property after the update. In the following case its null even though `Include` was called:

```
this.context.Update(childInstance);
await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
Child child = await this.context.Children
    .Include(p => p.Parent)
    .SingleAsync(p => p.Id == childInstance.Id);
```

In this case, what is the correct and efficient method to update a dependent model without knowing the parent navigation data at first and retrieving during update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `childInstance` is attached to the context and considered being current with shadow FK `ParentId` being `null` by the change tracker, so any further query returning entity with the same PK will be ignored and simply replaced with that instance.

One way to fix it is to detach the entity instance after save:

```
await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
this.context.Entry(childInstance).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

or reload it from the database:

```
await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
await this.context.Entry(childInstance).ReloadAsync();
```

Now you can load the navigation property:

```
await this.context.Entry(childInstance).Reference(c => c.Parent).LoadAsync();
```

But once you need to retrieve some data from the database after update, probably the better approach would be to reverse the procedure by first loading the entity instance from the database and then applying the changes. The additional benefit is that only modified properties will be included in the `UPDATE` command (or no update at all):

```
var dbChild = await this.context.Children
    .Include(p => p.Parent)
    .SingleAsync(p => p.Id == childInstance.Id);

// Update properties
dbChild.Name = childInstance.Name;
// ...

// Or more generically
this.context.Entry(dbChild).CurrentValues.SetValues(childInstance);

await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response, I took the latter approach and everything is working well.